# SSRS Reports URL

Tags: sql, reporting-services

How can i mask the SSRS url. I do not want to hide the toolbar. I do not want the user to see my server name and other details. I am using Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL reporting services in an asp.net application with some notes on report parameters

http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2005/11/15/using-sql-reporting-services-in-an-asp-net-application-with-some-notes-on-report-parameters/